# Converting RDF to SQL/RDBMS

Tags: sql, rdbms, rdf

I have found that there are a number of projects that can provide conversions from SQL to RDF. Is there anything that can go from RDF to SQL? It would preferably use the same mapping as SQL to RDF.

Comment: I can't think of any off the top of my head but you might get better answers asking over at answers.semanticweb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is the D2RQ/Update extension to D2RQ. It is currently experimental though.
http://d2rqupdate.cs.technion.ac.il/

Comment: I don't understand why this is flagged as accepted answer.  D2RQ allows doing updates and deletes through RDF of SQL-based data, it DOES NOT convert RDF to SQL at all.

Comment: @cnst: There might be a better option now, but at the time this was the closest solution I could find. Indeed it does not convert RDF to SQL, but it provided an alternative to conversion of the data.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this utility works or not, but I did some googling around and found it.

http://www.semwebcentral.org/projects/rdf2sql/

Comment: It appears to be written by someone from bbn.com under a BSD licence, but the project doesn't seem to be really usable, not even a README file, and it's not very obvious how to specify the input RDF file, doesn't seem to work with DMOZ ODP.  For DMOZ ODP RDFs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644675/how-do-i-convert-dmoz-odp-rdf-into-mysql.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [RDF2X](https://github.com/Merck/rdf2x) to convert RDF dumps to PostgreSQL or any other relational database.

It was tested on terabytes of data, you can [read my thesis](http://davidprihoda.com/rdf2x/Distributed_Conversion_of_RDF_Data_to_the_Relational_Model.pdf) for more info.

Comment: Your solution does not compile anymore and has a known vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the data to text/XML using SPARQL and load the data into SQL data base using SSIS. Or we can completely use SSIS